# Verificar tipo de dato de un EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola a todos tengo lo siguiente:

```
                // recojo 2 valores del EditText
                String valor1 = recullFrom.getText().toString();
                String valor2 = recullTo.getText().toString();
                // Transformarlos en int para usarlos
                int nro1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
                int nro2 = Integer.parseInt(valor2);
```

Como puedo hacer para verificar que el valor1 y valor2 son números ??

Necesito usarlos para un random y claro si pongo texto ahora mismo me lo cogería y me peta.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que en el layout del activity configures para que los datos de ese imput sólo puedan ser números.

```
<EditText 
   android:numeric="integer"
   android:inputType="number">
</EditText>
```

En caso de no querer hacer eso puedes meterlo en un `try` para determinar si es o no númerico.

```
try {
   int nro1 = Integer.parseInt(valor1);
   Log.i("",num+" is a number");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   Log.i("",nro1 +" is not a number");
}
```

Comment: me ha ido genial el  android:inputType="number"> con esto ya no necesito poner teclado con letras que es justo lo que necesito! gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion seria crear un metodo que confirme si es de tipo entero o no. A continuacion te dejo en ejemplo:

```
    public boolean isInteger(String numero){
        boolean resultado;
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(numero);
            resultado=true;
        }catch(Exception e){resultado=false;};

        return resultado;
    }
```

Si el metodo devuelve "true" entonces es un dato de tipo entero, si devuelve "false" entonces no lo es. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias! Usaré el del compañero que al final con una linea  android:inputType="number"> me hes suficiente!! mil .gracias igualmente!